# Why is Cloudwatch billing me for GetMetricData API calls in every regions? I run my app in a single region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

I've been combing through my AWS bills and noticed something strange - Cloudwatch bills a very small amount for every available region with a charge it lists as `$0.01 per 1,000 metrics requested using GetMetricData API - Asia Pacific (Singapore)` (or insert region here).

In my main region (US East) I see billing as expected - a few bucks total for PutLogEvents and GetMetricData calls, as you'd expect from normal use.

But in every other region I also have these costs - a few cents each - for GetMetricData calls in that region. Does anybody know the source of these costs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please take a look to https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/?nc1=h_ls

The Costs for GetMetricData and GetMetricWidgetImage is not applicaple for the free tier, you will have on your AWS account.
Do you deploy something in your account, which collects data from all your regions or you did not restrict the values for those metrics? E.g. if you are using 3rd party services like NewRelic, Datadog, etc. and collect those metrics, this API call is used to receive the list of all available metrics.